# i want to pass third date variable in this ...how i can pass??? date= $date= date("Y-m-d"); INSERT INTO article_likes (user, article,date)

Tags: php

i want to pass date variable in this how i can pass???

```
 date= $date= date("Y-m-d");
 $query = "  
           INSERT INTO article_likes (user, article)  
           SELECT {$_SESSION['user_id']}, {$id} FROM users   
            WHERE EXISTS(  
               SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid = {$id}) AND  
               NOT EXISTS(  
                  SELECT id FROM article_likes 
                  WHERE user = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND article = {$id})  
                  LIMIT 1  
           ";
```

Comment: There are so many subqueries I don't even know what's going on anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add your date column to insert query and add date variable in select query like

```
$date= date("Y-m-d");
 $query = "  
           INSERT INTO article_likes (user, article,date)  
           SELECT {$_SESSION['user_id']}, {$id},{$date} FROM users   
           WHERE EXISTS(  
           SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid = {$id}) AND  
           NOT EXISTS(  
           SELECT id FROM article_likes 
           WHERE user = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND article = {$id})  
           LIMIT 1 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear. Start easy. Do not give too many queries at first.

Also it is better to give the database and then the table in your query. 
Then, The table columns must fit exactly to your number of variables you send.

So if you have 3 columns in your table (id, my_user, date), you must write your query giving 3 variables which must fit to the type of variables accepted by your table (string, boolean, float etc.)

For instance, assuming articles_like is your table with 4 columns:
write this:

```
INSERT INTO `my_database_name`.`article_likes` (`id`, `my_user`,`article`, `my_date`) VALUES (`xxx`, `Darth_vader`,`New Fancy Laser Sword`, `2017-05-01`);
```

Watch if this works for you. If so, add the other queries like this .

```
SELECT `id` FROM `my_database_name`.`article_likes` where `my_user` = `Darth_Vader` AND `article` = `New Fancy Laser Sword`;
```

Then depending on the type of language you are using to send the variables dynamically (I think here its php), replace the constants shown by those variables.